# WinApi Taskmgr. Не принимает SendMessage()

Tags: c#, winapi

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь передать диспетчеру задач нажатие клавиши "Alt"

```
  static void Main()
    {
        MainForm = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "TaskManagerWindow", null);
        SendMessage(MainForm, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, 0x12, (int)MakeL(1,30));
        SendMessage(MainForm, WM_SYSKEYUP, 0x12, (int)MakeL(1,30));
    }
```

Хэндл окна верный, если верить spy++, то диспетчер не просто не реагирует на неверно сформированную команду, а они даже не доходят до него, подскажите в чем проблема, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нажатия клавиш симулируют с помощью функции [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), а не SendMessage.